# how to test objectContaining using jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have a test where I want to validate a function has been called
with a specific value and an object containing an array.

Following [this](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/24.1/expect#expectobjectcontainingobject) docs, I am executing the following test:

```
test('...', () => {
  ...
  expect(queue.publish).toBeCalledWith('fetch-part', expect.objectContaining({
    parts: expect.arrayContaining ([
      'a',
      'b'
    ])
  })
})
```

This test fails showing me that the received object is has values that not exist
in the expected, plus, it says that the order of the items in the array are important.

How can I test that a specific field (which is array) in an object contain some values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I test that a specific field (which is array) in an object contain some values?

Your approach is a good approach.

Here is a simple working example:

```
it('should work', () => {
  const spy = jest.fn();

  spy('fetch-part', {
    parts: ['z', 'c', 'b', 'y', 'a', 'x'],
    somethingElse: 'hello world'
  });

  expect(spy).toBeCalledWith('fetch-part', expect.objectContaining({
    parts: expect.arrayContaining([
      'a',
      'b'
    ])
  }));  // Success!
});
```

---

**Update**

OP mentioned in comments that they decided to use [`.mock.calls`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockcalls) to get the argument and test it directly:

```
it('should work', () => {
  const spy = jest.fn();

  spy('fetch-part', {
    parts: ['z', 'c', 'b', 'y', 'a', 'x'],
    somethingElse: 'hello world'
  });

  expect(spy.mock.calls[0][1].parts).toContain('a', 'b');  // Success!
});
```

Comment: I ended up using a spy and its `calls` array, I found it much more versatile and concise

Comment: nice, that works as well.  I added that approach to the answer above @natdev